# ImportError: No module named tarfile in Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-2.7

I get the ImportError: No module named tarfile when i do an import tarfile on my python 2.7.17 instance

I know that tarfile module is supposed to be part of Python since 2.3 and I know for a fact I am running 2.7 so not sure how it could "loose" this module...

Other questions on this forum about this issue always pointed to the fact that the person was running python 2.2 where it was not yet part of the standard libraries, but clearly that is not this issue here...

Am I missing some other obvious paths in my sys.path?

This is running on a docker instance with a read only root file system.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.17 (default, Apr 15 2020, 17:20:14) 
[GCC 7.5.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.version
2.7.17 (default, Apr 15 2020, 17:20:14) 
[GCC 7.5.0]
>>> print '\n'.join(sys.path)

/data
/usr/local/src
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
>>> import tarfile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tarfile
```

Comment: Python 2 is EOL... Why do you need this?

Comment: It is used in an install of BGEN/regenie as something called waf. We found a workaround, but the fact that 2.7 is EOL is not the reason that this is not working...

Answer (score 0):

Which Docker image are you using? Works fine with Alpine

```
$ docker run --rm -ti python:2.7-alpine
Unable to find image 'python:2.7-alpine' locally
2.7-alpine: Pulling from library/python
aad63a933944: Already exists 
259d822268fb: Pull complete 
10ba96d218d3: Pull complete 
44ba9f6a4209: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:724d0540eb56ffaa6dd770aa13c3bc7dfc829dec561d87cb36b2f5b9ff8a760a
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:2.7-alpine
Python 2.7.18 (default, Apr 20 2020, 19:51:05) 
[GCC 9.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tarfile
>>> dir(tarfile)
['AREGTYPE', 'BLKTYPE', 'BLOCKSIZE', 'CHRTYPE', 'CONTTYPE', 'CompressionError', 'DEFAULT_FORMAT', 'DIRTYPE', 'ENCODING', 'EOFHeaderError', 'EmptyHeaderError', 'ExFileObject', 'ExtractError', 'FIFOTYPE', 'GNUTYPE_LONGLINK', 'GNUTYPE_LONGNAME', 'GNUTYPE_SPARSE', 'GNU_FORMAT', 'GNU_MAGIC', 'GNU_TYPES', 'HeaderError', 'InvalidHeaderError', 'LENGTH_LINK', 'LENGTH_NAME', 'LENGTH_PREFIX', 'LNKTYPE', 'NUL', 'PAX_FIELDS', 'PAX_FORMAT', 'PAX_NUMBER_FIELDS', 'POSIX_MAGIC', 'RECORDSIZE', 'REGTYPE', 'REGULAR_TYPES', 'ReadError', 'SOLARIS_XHDTYPE', 'SUPPORTED_TYPES', 'SYMTYPE', 'S_IFBLK', 'S_IFCHR', 'S_IFDIR', 'S_IFIFO', 'S_IFLNK', 'S_IFREG', 'StreamError', 'SubsequentHeaderError', 'TAR_GZIPPED', 'TAR_PLAIN', 'TGEXEC', 'TGREAD', 'TGWRITE', 'TOEXEC', 'TOREAD', 'TOWRITE', 'TSGID', 'TSUID', 'TSVTX', 'TUEXEC', 'TUREAD', 'TUWRITE', 'TarError', 'TarFile', 'TarFileCompat', 'TarInfo', 'TarIter', 'TruncatedHeaderError', 'USTAR_FORMAT', 'XGLTYPE', 'XHDTYPE', '_BZ2Proxy', '_FileInFile', '_LowLevelFile', '_Stream', '_StreamProxy', '__all__', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__credits__', '__cvsid__', '__date__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__version__', '_data', '_hole', '_ringbuffer', '_section', 'bltn_open', 'calc_chksums', 'copy', 'copyfileobj', 'errno', 'filemode', 'filemode_table', 'grp', 'is_tarfile', 'itn', 'nti', 'nts', 'open', 'operator', 'os', 'pwd', 're', 'shutil', 'stat', 'stn', 'struct', 'sys', 'time', 'uts', 'version']
```

Comment: ubuntu:bionic-20200219

Comment: I suggest trying the actual python image, some of which are built on ubuntu